# How to group dataframe and after transpose combine in python for python 3.6 with pandas 1.15.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

This question already has answers here:
How can I pivot a dataframe? (3 answers)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 2 hours ago.

(Private feedback for you)

I have one dataframe with 4 columns i want to group dataframe by ID and do transpose of each group and at the end all groups combine in one dataframe.

```
here is my example df:

df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'value1':[1,33,56,7,7,8,8,67,88],'dd':[1,1,1,7,7,7,8,8,8]})


required_df=pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,7,8],'2':[33,7,67],'3':[56,8,88],'dd':[1,7,8]})

tried :

df.pivot(index='dd', columns='ID', values='value1')

result:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaILQ.png)

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                'value1':[1,33,56,7,7,8,8,67,88],
                'dd':[1,1,1,7,7,7,8,8,8]})


print (df.pivot(index='dd', columns='ID', values='value1'))
ID  1   2   3
dd           
1   1  33  56
7   7   7   8
8   8  67  88
```

Comment: Why consider this as duplicate , i can't find solution in this question

Comment: If you use `pivot` and not working, can you change data for show your problem? Becasue in sample data `df.pivot(index='dd', columns='ID', values='value1')` working nice

Comment: Problem is not in pandas version, but in data.

Comment: i used df in my question and added result , you can see here results are not what i want

Comment: So use `df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'value1':[1,33,56,7,7,8,8,67,88],'dd':[1,1,1,7,7,7,8,8,8]})` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Added to question my ouput. Your is different?

Comment: yes , my result are different